# Having trouble acquiring the current posts title

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I am currently working in wordpress and I have a link that is supposed to play a `wav` file depending on the title of the post. So if the post title is `'one'` then it should play `one.wav` from the uploads folder. However, the sound file on every post only plays the most current posts title. So if I added a post called `two` and then a post called `one`, both posts will play `one.wav`.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<span id="dummy"></span>
<a class="playSound" onclick="playSound();" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</a>
```

JQuery

```
function playSound() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sound.php',
            data: "getSound",
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= "<embed src=\""+data+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"loop=\"false\" />";
            }
        });
}
```

and the PHP

```
<?php
  require('./wp-blog-header.php');

  if(isset($_GET['getSound'])) {
    $file='wp-content/uploads/2015/wav/' . get_the_title() . '.wav';
    echo $file;  
  }
?>
```

I assume `get_the_title()` is the proper call but at this point I am not so sure. I have tried all the other call functions but still no luck. I assume at this point is has to do with the loading of the page and storing the initial posts title but i am just lost at this point.

Comment: get_the_title() needs the post_id https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: Sounds like your php code is outside of [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: possibly. I have changed the code to just use javascript as suggested by @poostchi. Any suggestions on how to get it in the loop? I'm assuming its locking that file name when it runs through the first post. I'm still rather new to this.

Comment: In case it must be known, I have the function inside my themes function js file and the html inside the content.php file. I thought the loop ran through content.php for every post and assumed that would be a safe place to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$sound_query = new WP_Query();
    if ($sound_query->have_posts()):
        while ($sound_query->have_posts()):
        $sound_query->the_post();
?>
<script>
function playSound() {
   document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= "<embed src='wp-content/uploads/2015/wav/<?php echo get_the_title() ?>.wav' />";
}
</script>

<?php 
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: If content.php is called within the loop and my code is within content.php, does that mean its in the loop? or do I have to put it somewhere else?

Comment: `content.php` is not a base file http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development so I don't know what gets loaded there. It may be that your loop is running there, or not. But because `get_the_title()` doesn't work as expected, I suppose there is no loop there. Anyway, I updated my code based on @poostchi because he is right, you don't need ajax for this

Comment: Figured it out! I just plugged the function into my themes header file and everything worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change your sound.php file code like

```
<?php

require('./wp-blog-header.php');

  global $post;
  setup_postdata( $post );

  if(isset($_GET['getSound'])) {
    $file='wp-content/uploads/2015/wav/' . get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) . '.wav';
    echo $file;  
  }
?>
```

Comment: still having the same issue =( Well I mean it still plays but just not the proper .wav file

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get ride of your second php code and just use javascript:

```
function playSound() {
            document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= "<embed src='wp-content/uploads/2015/wav/<?php echo get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) ?>.wav' />";
}
```

Comment: That would of saved me a couple hours in the past. Unfortunately it's still playing the most recent posts wav file

Answer (score 0):

Everything is disjointed. The JS file doesn't know what post you are trying to target, and hence the sound.php file doesn't know either.

Pass the post ID to the JS file and then pass it to the sound.php file, then extract the post from that.

Also, try not using the post title for such things, use the ID as the post title and post name can be changed.

Example:

HTML

```
<a class="playSound" onclick="playSound(<?php echo $post->ID; ?>);" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</a>
```

JS

```
function playSound(postID) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'sound.php',
    data: data: {"postID": postID
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "html",
    success: function(data) {
      //Function here
   })
}
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['postID'])) {
  $file='wp-content/uploads/2015/wav/' . $_GET['postID'] . '.wav';
  echo $file;  
}
```

Or something similar to that anyway.